# kVTVideoDecoderBadDataErr when using VTDecompressionSessionDecodeFrame and H264 NAL units

Tags: h.264, video-codecs, video-toolbox

My code can successfully extract all the NAL units of a H264 stream, that is packed into an Avi-File. I can also parse the SPS, PPS and the NAL unit types 1 and 5. I then extract a whole GOP (group of pictures), starting with the SPS and PPS, followed by the IDR NAL unit and ends with the last non IDR NAL unit before the next SPS.

I then reorder the NAL units according to 8.2 of the specification to get the correct PicOrderCnt (to pass it as the playing timestamp, PTS).

So I have an array with the NAL units of the GOP and a second array with the PTS of the NAL units.

I then change the start code to the AVC format (length of the NAL unit).

After that, I put the SPS and PPS without the start code to the `CMVideoFormatDescriptionCreateFromH264ParameterSets`.

Afterwards I put all the NAL units ([UInt8]-array) to the `CMSampleBuffer`, using the PicOrderCnt as the `CMSampleTimingInfo`.

My code then successfully decodes the video frames when using `VTDecompressionSessionDecodeFrame`.

Unfortunately, some GOP don't work, for some frames I get the error `kVTVideoDecoderBadDataErr` and I can't explain why.

For example: My actual group is starting by DTS (decoding time stamp) 770, what is a keyframe. This is from my debug print:

```
DTS: 770    | PTS: 771  | NAL-Type 5: frame_num: 0 // slice_type: 7 // pic_order_cnt_lsb: 0     |   PicOrderCnt: 0
DTS: 771    | PTS: 773  | NAL-Type 1: frame_num: 1 // slice_type: 5 // pic_order_cnt_lsb: 4     |   PicOrderCnt: 4
DTS: 772    | PTS: 772  | NAL-Type 1: frame_num: 2 // slice_type: 6 // pic_order_cnt_lsb: 2     |   PicOrderCnt: 2
DTS: 773    | PTS: 776  | NAL-Type 1: frame_num: 2 // slice_type: 5 // pic_order_cnt_lsb: 10    |   PicOrderCnt: 10
DTS: 774    | PTS: 775  | NAL-Type 1: frame_num: 3 // slice_type: 6 // pic_order_cnt_lsb: 8     |   PicOrderCnt: 8
DTS: 775    | PTS: 774  | NAL-Type 1: frame_num: 4 // slice_type: 6 // pic_order_cnt_lsb: 6     |   PicOrderCnt: 6
DTS: 776    | PTS: 779  | NAL-Type 1: frame_num: 4 // slice_type: 5 // pic_order_cnt_lsb: 16    |   PicOrderCnt: 16

...

DTS: 815    | PTS: 818  | NAL-Type 1: frame_num: 14 // slice_type: 5 // pic_order_cnt_lsb: 30   |   PicOrderCnt: 94
DTS: 816    | PTS: 817  | NAL-Type 1: frame_num: 15 // slice_type: 6 // pic_order_cnt_lsb: 28   |   PicOrderCnt: 92
DTS: 817    | PTS: 816  | NAL-Type 1: frame_num: 0 // slice_type: 6 // pic_order_cnt_lsb: 26    |   PicOrderCnt: 90
DTS: 818    | PTS: 821  | NAL-Type 1: frame_num: 0 // slice_type: 5 // pic_order_cnt_lsb: 36    |   PicOrderCnt: 100
DTS: 819    | PTS: 820  | NAL-Type 1: frame_num: 1 // slice_type: 6 // pic_order_cnt_lsb: 34    |   PicOrderCnt: 98
DTS: 820    | PTS: 819  | NAL-Type 1: frame_num: 2 // slice_type: 6 // pic_order_cnt_lsb: 32    |   PicOrderCnt: 96
DTS: 821    | PTS: 824  | NAL-Type 1: frame_num: 2 // slice_type: 5 // pic_order_cnt_lsb: 42    |   PicOrderCnt: 106
DTS: 822    | PTS: 823  | NAL-Type 1: frame_num: 3 // slice_type: 6 // pic_order_cnt_lsb: 40    |   PicOrderCnt: 104
DTS: 823    | PTS: 822  | NAL-Type 1: frame_num: 4 // slice_type: 6 // pic_order_cnt_lsb: 38    |   PicOrderCnt: 102
DTS: 824    | PTS: 827  | NAL-Type 1: frame_num: 4 // slice_type: 5 // pic_order_cnt_lsb: 48    |   PicOrderCnt: 112
DTS: 825    | PTS: 826  | NAL-Type 1: frame_num: 5 // slice_type: 6 // pic_order_cnt_lsb: 46    |   PicOrderCnt: 110
```

I get errors starting at PTS 819.

This is my code:

```
func decodeGroup(_ group: AviH264Analyzer.GOP, fps: Double) {
    DispatchQueue(label: "decode").async {
                                                    
        let sps = group.spsNAL.bytesWithoutStartCode
        let pps = group.ppsNAL.bytesWithoutStartCode
        
        var formatDesc: CMVideoFormatDescription?
        
        var status = sps.withUnsafeBufferPointer { spsPtr in
            pps.withUnsafeBufferPointer { ppsPtr in
                let paramSet = [spsPtr.baseAddress!, ppsPtr.baseAddress!]
                let paramSizes = [sps.count, pps.count]
                return paramSet.withUnsafeBufferPointer { paramSetPtr in
                    paramSizes.withUnsafeBufferPointer { paramSizesPtr in
                        CMVideoFormatDescriptionCreateFromH264ParameterSets(allocator: nil,
                                                                            parameterSetCount: 2,
                                                                            parameterSetPointers: paramSetPtr.baseAddress!,
                                                                            parameterSetSizes: paramSizesPtr.baseAddress!,
                                                                            nalUnitHeaderLength: 4,
                                                                            formatDescriptionOut: &formatDesc)
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
        
        var callback = VTDecompressionOutputCallbackRecord()
        callback.decompressionOutputCallback = { (_, _, status, _, imageBuffer, pts, _) in
            if let imageBuffer {
                let ciImage = CIImage(cvImageBuffer: imageBuffer)
                if let cgImage = CIContext().createCGImage(ciImage, from: ciImage.extent)  {
                    let rep = NSBitmapImageRep(cgImage: cgImage)
                    if let imgData = rep.representation(using: .png, properties: [:]), let nsImage = NSImage(data: imgData) {
                        let frameNumber = Int(pts.value)-1
                        if !VideoBuffer.shared.buffer.map({ $0.frameNumber }).contains(frameNumber) {
                            VideoBuffer.shared.buffer.append(VideoFrame(frameNumber: frameNumber, image: nsImage))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        let decoderParameters = NSMutableDictionary()
        let destinationPixelBufferAttributes = NSMutableDictionary()
        destinationPixelBufferAttributes.setValue(
            NSNumber(value: kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB),
            forKey: kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String
        )
        
        var decompressionSession: VTDecompressionSession?
        status = VTDecompressionSessionCreate(allocator: kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                              formatDescription: formatDesc!,
                                              decoderSpecification: decoderParameters,
                                              imageBufferAttributes: destinationPixelBufferAttributes,
                                              outputCallback: &callback,
                                              decompressionSessionOut: &decompressionSession)
        if status != noErr {
            handleStatus(status)
        } else {
            print("DecompressionSession sucessfully created")
        }
            
        let nalus = group.nalus
        
        self.decodeNALUnits(nalus: nalus, 
                            order: group.order,
                            fps: fps,
                            formatDesc: formatDesc!,
                            decompressionSession: decompressionSession!)
    }
}

func decodeNALUnits(nalus: [PictureNAL], order: [Int], fps: Double, formatDesc: CMVideoFormatDescription, decompressionSession: VTDecompressionSession) {
    var videoData = [UInt8]()
    var sampleSizeArray = [Int]()
    for nalu in nalus {
        var bytes = nalu.bytesWithoutStartCode
        
        // the length of the NALU
        var bigLen = CFSwapInt32HostToBig(UInt32(bytes.count))
        bytes.insert(contentsOf: withUnsafeBytes(of: &bigLen, { Array($0) }), at: 0)
        videoData += bytes
        
        sampleSizeArray.append(bytes.count)
    }
    
    var blockBuffer: CMBlockBuffer?
    let count = videoData.count
    var status = videoData.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { bufferPointer in
        return CMBlockBufferCreateWithMemoryBlock(allocator: kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                  memoryBlock: bufferPointer.baseAddress!,
                                                  blockLength: count,
                                                  blockAllocator: kCFAllocatorNull,
                                                  customBlockSource: nil,
                                                  offsetToData: 0,
                                                  dataLength: count,
                                                  flags: 0,
                                                  blockBufferOut: &blockBuffer)
    }
    
    if status != noErr {
        handleStatus(status)
    } else {
        print("CMBlockBufferCreateWithMemoryBlock sucess")
    }
    
    let frameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: Int32(fps))
    
    var timing = [CMSampleTimingInfo]()
    
    for i in 0..<nalus.count {
        let pts = order[i]
        let presentationTime = CMTimeMake(value: Int64(pts), timescale: Int32(fps))
        let timingInfo = CMSampleTimingInfo(duration: frameDuration,
                                            presentationTimeStamp: presentationTime,
                                            decodeTimeStamp: CMTime.invalid)
        timing.append(timingInfo)
    }
    
    var sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?
    status = CMSampleBufferCreateReady(allocator: kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                       dataBuffer: blockBuffer,
                                       formatDescription: formatDesc,
                                       sampleCount: sampleSizeArray.count,
                                       sampleTimingEntryCount: timing.count,
                                       sampleTimingArray: &timing,
                                       sampleSizeEntryCount: sampleSizeArray.count,
                                       sampleSizeArray: sampleSizeArray,
                                       sampleBufferOut: &sampleBuffer)
    if status != noErr {
        handleStatus(status)
    } else {
        print("CMSampleBufferCreateReady sucess")
    }
    
    guard let buffer = sampleBuffer else {
        print("Could not unwrap sampleBuffer!")
        return
    }
    
    var outputBuffer: CVPixelBuffer?
    
    status = VTDecompressionSessionDecodeFrame(decompressionSession,
                                               sampleBuffer: buffer,
                                               flags: [._EnableAsynchronousDecompression, ._EnableTemporalProcessing],
                                               frameRefcon: &outputBuffer,
                                               infoFlagsOut: nil)
    
    if status != noErr {
        print(status)
        handleStatus(status)
    } else {
        print("VTDecompressionSessionDecodeFrame sucess")
    }
}
```

Comment: Any chance the video itself has an issue? [Reading this](https://ottverse.com/i-p-b-frames-idr-keyframes-differences-usecases/), H.264 streams contain different types of frames: (I-frame, P-frame, B-frame): If there is an error in the stream - say, a missing or corrupted I-frame - then all P-frames and B-frames that depend on the missing I-frame cannot be decoded, which might be the cause of the `kVTVideoDecoderBadDataErr` error.

Comment: Unfortunately I have the same error with other files too. And they can be played perfectly in VLC

Comment: OK, although VLC has a robust and fault-tolerant video decoding system, so it might be more forgiving of certain issues that would cause the Video Toolbox decoder to fail.

Comment: How can I find out? If there are failures, I could correct them. ffplay works as well btw.

Comment: And I think this is not the problem. I took one video and converted it to a MP4-File. This plays perfectly with QuickTime. I then extracted the h264-raw stream out of this mp4 file, I also get the problems of `kVTVideoDecoderBadDataErr`, but not for all frames. I guess it has to do with my code. I read, that it's the wrong guess, if you say that every NAL unit with type 1 or 5 is one specific frame. Maybe this is the error, I give too much samples to `CMSampleBufferCreateReady`? But I don't know how to find the correct amount of samples.

Comment: To make sure, would a `ffprobe -show_frames -print_format json path_to_your_video_file > output.json` help? Specifically, you might want to look for frames with the key_frame property set to 1 (these are the I-frames). If there are unusually long gaps between these frames, or if there are any errors reported in the output, that might give you some clues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253758/discussion-between-vonc-and-lupurus).

Answer (score 2):

I cannot believe this .... I found the solution by comparing the NAL units from my own parser to the NAL units parsed by libav. The only difference I could find was, that my parser deletes the emulation prevention byte (7.3.1 of the H264 specification). After some trial and error, this is my solution:

1. SPS and PPS must be passed WITHOUT emulation prevention byte (remove 0x03 in 0x000003) and without start code (0x000001 or 0x00000001) to `CMVideoFormatDescriptionCreateFromH264ParameterSets`
2. VCL-nal units must be passed in AVCC format and WITH emulation prevention byte to `VTDecompressionSessionDecodeFrame`.